# Poor text quality due to encoding

Tags: fonts, text, russian

The quality of my font turns out to be bad due to the encoding. I did not find an answer among similar questions. I need to print in Russian text

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel} 

\begin{document}
    0о)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That doesn't happen for me. Which TeX distribution are you using?

Comment: I use Tex Studio 2.12.22

Comment: That is an editor, not relevant, which latex installation do you use. I have seen latex use bitmap fonts for Russian before (even if his is not Russian text)

Comment: Under my TeXLive 2020 this example uses cm-super vector fonts (using pdflatex) and not bit map like the above. So either you are using MikTeX which does not install CM-Super by default (it is the default in TeXLive), if using MikTeX it is highly recommended to install cm-super or you have installed a very minimal TeXLive that did not use CM-Super as the default font.

Comment: Generally speaking, yes, I installed CM-Super and the problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:

1. Removed all programs
2. Downloaded and installed "Tex Studio 3.0.4"
3. Downloaded and installed "MiKteX 4.1"
4. I went to "MiKteX" - "Package"- and installed "cm-super"
   All! The fonts are sleek!